# update field with picklist values

Tags: formula, picklist

I have a picklist list with the following values: YES, NO, MAYBE. I have another formula field that calculates the value of YES, NO, and MAYBE by assigning to each of them a particular score: YES = 10, NO = 0, MAYBE = BLANK.

When I add this field to a report the records with any of the three values is shows the number of points, that is, 10 or 0 or BLANK, and calculates the average result based on the different scores.

I need to show on the reports only the records scoring YES or NO and remove MAYBE. Then the average would be calculated based on the total number of YES and NO instead of the total number of YES, NO, and MAYBE.

How can I do this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just filter the report to only show records where the picklist field does not equal "Maybe"?

[Video Tutorial on filtering reports](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NWonqBubxQ)